# Magento: How to change the limit of a specific product list? 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Magento CE Version 1.8

On my Homepage CMS Site i have this Code to display a List of Products (NO Grid):

`{{block type='catalog/product_list' limit='20' category_id='6'  hide_toolbar='1' template='catalog/product/list_home.phtml'}}`

My Shop is configured so that it displays 10 List Items as default.
Allowed Values are 10,20,30,40,50 and Show-All is allowed.

I want to configure the Block to show me 20 Items instead of 10.
list_home.phtml is nearly the same as the standard list.phtml (only some markup changes, no PHP changes)

As you can see i tried it with limit='20' and i also tried it with limit=all.
Cache is not active.

What do i have to do to let this list display 20 items instead of default 10?

Comment: Most likely your file list_home.phtml is being forced to show 10 products, instead of than getting it dynamically from the call to it. Check in the list_home.phtml file where you see the "foreach" loop.

Comment: no, this is not the case. The $_productCollection as defined in the first PHP Statement of the file ( $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection(); ) only has a size of 10.